# Can I constantly run motors for an extended periods of time?

Tags: dc-motor

I want to run a small DC Pittman gearhead motor rated at 12VDC continuously for an art piece.

Can the motors withstand running 12-14 hours on a lower than 12v?

The load is very small.

Comment: You'll get better operation at low speeds if you drive it with PWM.

Comment: A thing you need to know - motors with a duty cycle rating of "intermittent" are frequently more robust than their "continuous" counterparts; they have to be able to withstand frequent and potentially brutal start/stop transients, and may not come to temperature equlibrium. Be sure to read and understand all specifications.

Answer (score 1):

Pittman motors don't appear to be hobby or toy motors. They appear to be designed for continuous use. Lower than max voltage would be reduced speed. They may have some minimum speed for continuous operation. You should look carefully at the specifications for the specific motor and gear that you intend to use. Check the gear efficiency. Even if the driven load is very small, you need to consider that these motors are very small and a significant percentage of the motor power may be required to overcome friction in the gear.